# "nginx is not running" - but it actually is

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Running Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 LTS

Checking nginx status says it's not running:

```
 $ sudo service nginx status
  * nginx is not running
```

However, it is, as the websites it's powering are working, and:

Processes exist:

```
$ ps aux | grep nginx
root      1445  0.0  0.2  86008  1448 ?        Ss   18:06   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
www-data  1446  0.0  0.3  86320  1868 ?        S    18:06   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data  1447  0.0  0.3  86320  1868 ?        S    18:06   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data  1448  0.0  0.3  86320  1868 ?        S    18:06   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data  1449  0.0  0.4  86320  2372 ?        S    18:06   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

And netstat shows it listening:

```
$ sudo netstat -tlnp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1445/nginx
```

The upshot of this strangeness is that if I change a setting I can't do `service nginx reload` and instead have to killall nginx and then start it again (using service nginx start).

How can I fix this?

Comment: The service status is likely based on the PID value in a file. If that PID isn't a currently running process, then the service status command will show as down, even though nginx is running under a different PID.

Comment: @CoverosGene there's an entry in `/var/run/nginx.pid` and one in `/run/nginx.pid` and both have the same correct value as referenced in ps aux's output.

Comment: Look in the /etc/init.d/nginx script, and see what file or condition it is looking for.

Comment: It's looking for /run/nginx.pid if there isn't a config entry in nginx.conf - there is, and it's pointed at the same location.

Comment: The thing is, it's a clean install of ngnix on a Digital Ocean box. It shouldn't be misconfigured from the get go.

Comment: To the downvoter - please explain what is unclear so I can revise the question.

Answer (score 2):

I updated nginx and got same problem on Ubuntu 12.04.

I switched to root user and then killed all nginx process.

`kill $(ps aux | grep '[n]ginx' | awk '{print $2}')`

After then started to nginx, and everything seems fine.